# Как проверить, что юзер залогинился?

Tags: java, android

Я работаю с SQLite, и у меня есть форма регистрации. Когда юзер зарегистрирован, то данные сохраняются в таблицу, но приложение просит каждый раз выполнить log in. Можно ли выполнить проверку, был ли уже зарегистрирован current юзер, и если да, то пропустить регистрацию?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется нужно использовать SharedPreferences... 
Когда юзер проходит через форму регистрации или logIn и все удачно, то сохраняем его logIn и пароль в SharedPreferences и в следующий раз когда он откроет приложение то в onCreate сделать проверку, достаем записанные данные и проверяем есть ли они в таблице, если да то возвращаем конкретного юзера. Когда юзер нажимает logOut то стираем данные из SharedPreferences

Comment: Да, например так. Если же пользовател подразумевается один, то достаточно выяснить есть ли вообще хоть одна запись в таблице юзеров.

Comment: Но в таком случае и не нужна таблица юзеров если подразумевается, что пользователь один))

Comment: Проще можно завести переменную Boolean isLogin; и сохранять именно ее при запуске и выходе, используя конечно SharedPreferences. Остается перед выводом формы регистрации убедиться, что if (isLogin == true) ...

Comment: Да но в таком случае как ты будешь знать какого именно юзера вернуть?

Answer (score 1):

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String email = settings.getString("email", "");
            String password = settings.getString("pword", "");
            inputEmail.setText(email);
            inputPassword.setText(password);

if(inputEmail.getText().toString().length() != 0 && inputPassword.getText().toString().length()!=0){
    //code допуск
}//проверка на длину
```

Вставляются данные логина (в данном случае email и password) в кэш, потом мы проверяем, если длины строк, которые в кэше не равны нулю, то даем добро на допуск к контенту, обратно и так ясно.
P.s. создайте для этого дела отдельно PREFRENCES_NAME, чтобы лишние "другие" данные не хранились именно в нем.

Comment: хммм... я просто реализовал для Вас код, который был дан в описании выше "Мне кажется нужно использовать SharedPreferences... Когда юзер проходит через форму регистрации или logIn и все удачно, то сохраняем его logIn и пароль в SharedPreferences и в следующий раз когда он откроет приложение то в onCreate сделать проверку, достаем записанные данные и проверяем есть ли они в таблице, если да то возвращаем конкретного юзера."

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно. Если вы записываете какие-либо данные о пользователе при его регистрации, то просто проверьте наличие этих данных в БД перед показом окна регистрации....

Comment: Да, но с чем сравнивать? Допустим юзер залогинился в таблицу было записано ИД, имя и пароль... Потом закрыл приложение и снова открыл... Как приложение поймет тот же юзер или нет? Что приложение должно проверять?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, если юзер не один на устройство, то никак не определить и вам придётся **всегда** заставлять его логиниться. Определить тот же это человек или нет однозначно абсолютно невозможно. Мы ж не будет пытаться делать это через распонавание лица фронтальной камерой, сканером пальцев и анализом ДНК.

Comment: Согласен, но когда я на своем устройстве один раз зашел допустим в приложение VK то я не ввожу свои данные каждый раз... Видимо они что то знают о моем ДНК )))

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, беда в том, что если другой человек возьмёт ваш телефон, то логин из ВК не пропадёт.