# Как создать регистрацию на андроид?

Tags: java, android

Хотел бы построить приложения с регистрацией, но статей как это реализовать просто нету.Как создать регистрацию в приложении на андроид? Также как же сделать что бы была автоматическая авторизация приложения? Существует ли какой-то конкретный алгоритм?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь одни каким-то большим алгоритмом не обойтись....

И одного Java будет мало....

Вот Вам в помощь сильная статья: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

P.s. Если разберетесь и настроите, то будет Вам счастье:)

Ответ с алгоритмом на вопрос про автоматическую авторизацию я уже давал тут: [Как проверить, что юзер залогинился?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504767/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F/504815#504815)

Comment: Так можно написать бекенд на Spring.io. Хотя может на php быстрее

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать экран регистрации
2. При вводе логина и пароля сохранять информацию у юзере в БД (перед этим нужно создать БД). Либо сохранять значения в SharedPreferences.
3. Пользователь зарегистрирован, PROFIT