# Android. Нужно создать регистрацию в приложении

Tags: android

Создаю приложение на android (подобие социальной сети), которое предполагает регистрацию пользователя. Заходим в приложение, регистрируемся, заполняем свой профиль (имя, возраст и пр.) и запускается активити - профиль пользователя с его фото, личными данными. Думаю, что идея понятна. Сейчас нахожусь на стадии создания регистрации в приложении. Подскажите, как реализовать обмен приложения с сервером на PHP (на хостинге) ? Желательно на русском языке, либо готовые исходники.

Comment: Создаёте серверную часть на `php`, которая получает `сериализованные JSON` данные от приложения, и возвращает назад необходимые данные. Обычные `POST`\`GET`запросы.

Comment: Я уже отвечал на данную тему: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506620/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4/506655#506655