# Как организовать свою авторизацию с токеном на Android?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!

Программированию я еще только учусь, и сейчас пишу клиент на Android под web-ресурс. Как организовать простейшую авторизацию между Android приложением и сервером на php я понимаю. Но не совсем разобрался, как мне сделать так, чтобы я отправлял на сервер username и password, а уже от сервера принимал токен и записывал его в shared preferences, для дальнейшей авторизации уже по токену. Как отдать токен с сервера я понимаю, интересует именно как принять токен на Android и записать его в хранилище для последующей авторизации уже по нему.

Comment: json в помощь:) Ps: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506620/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4/506655#506655

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, постараюсь разобраться.

Comment: Постарайтесь обязательно! окупится сполна :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня как раз сделан проект по этому поводу

Описание моего асинхронного потока

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import ru.diitcenter.labbaik.utils.DownloadListner;
import ru.diitcenter.labbaik.utils.ApplicationContext;
import ru.diitcenter.labbaik.internet.base.Make;
import ru.diitcenter.labbaik.internet.base.ReturnTypeData;
import ru.diitcenter.labbaik.utils.CommonUtilities;

public class StreamAuth extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ReturnTypeData> {

private String name_familia;
private String date;
private String pass;
private DownloadListner listner;
ReturnTypeData itemResult;

public StreamAuth(DownloadListner listner, String name_familia,    String date, String pass) {  // интерфейс
    this.listner = listner;
    try {
        this.name_familia = URLEncoder.encode(name_familia, "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.date = date;
    this.pass = pass;
}

@Override
protected ReturnTypeData doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if (pass.equals("")){
        itemResult = new Make().getJsonObject("GET", CommonUtilities.URL_AUTHOR1+"?fio=" + name_familia + "&date=" + date, null, CommonUtilities.TAG_AUTHOR1);
        if (itemResult.innerError == 0 && itemResult.error == 0) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = itemResult.jsonObject;

                SharedPreferences sPref = ApplicationContext.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences("SavedIdToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
                ed.putLong("id", Long.parseLong(object.getString("id")));
                ed.putString("token", object.getString("token"));
                ed.apply();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(CommonUtilities.TAG_AUTHOR1, "ошибка парсинга- фио и дата");
            }
        }

    } else{
        //Log.e("StreamAuth.pass",""+pass);
        itemResult = new Make().getJsonObject("GET", CommonUtilities.URL_AUTHOR2+"?fio=" + name_familia + "&pass=" + pass, null, CommonUtilities.TAG_AUTHOR1);
        if (itemResult.innerError == 0 && itemResult.error == 0) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = itemResult.jsonObject;

                SharedPreferences sPref = ApplicationContext.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences("SavedIdToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
                ed.putLong("id", Long.parseLong(object.getString("id")));
                ed.putString("token", object.getString("token"));
                ed.apply();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(CommonUtilities.TAG_AUTHOR1, "ошибка парсинга - фио и пароль");
            }
        }
    }
    return itemResult;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ReturnTypeData item) {
    super.onPostExecute(item);

    if (listner == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (item.innerError != 0) {
        Toast.makeText(ApplicationContext.getAppContext(), item.innerErrorInfo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        listner.downloadFinish(false);
    }
    if (item.error != 0) {
        Toast.makeText(ApplicationContext.getAppContext(), item.error_info, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        listner.downloadFinish(false);
    } else {
        listner.downloadFinish(true);
    }
}

}
```

А вот как записывать в Преференс

```
 SharedPreferences sPref = ApplicationContext.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences("SavedGPSlocation", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// ApplicationContext.getAppContext() - мой класс, я просто вытаскиваю context программы
// SavedGPSlocation - название файла преференса. При работе с преференсом выбирай нужный. 
//Context.MODE_PRIVATE или просто MODE_PRIVATE - это тип доступа. Тебе должен подойти этот
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit(); // настройка на редактирование
        ed.putString("znachenie1", znachenie1);//внести в  поле "znachenie1" своё значение
        ed.putString("znachenie2", znachenie2);
        ed.putString("action", action);
        ed.putInt("server", 0); // внести 0 в строку сервера
        ed.apply(); //принять
```

А вот, как считывать

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SavedIdToken", MODE_PRIVATE);
            long id = sharedPreferences.getLong("id", 0);
            String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", "");
```

Где: getLong("id", 0) - это вытащить значение поля или вытащить 0 по умолчанию

getString("token", "") - в строке по умолчанию у меня выводится пустота

Если что-то не понятно, спрашивай в комментах, буду рад помочь

Comment: Спасибо большое, уже сам додумался как всё сделать, но всё равно рад что откликнулись.

Comment: @Александр Шибаев,  пожалуйста)